# Angular 9: disabled attribute different behavior in chrome and IE 11

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

I had a simple template with a fromGroup and bunch of form controls, and I'm trying to enable a button if the form is valid.

**.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.minLength(3)],
      lastName: ['', Validators.minLength(5)]
    });
  }
}
```

**.html:**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div>
    <span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Test</span>
    <input [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

from the above example, the expectation is by default the button should be disabled and once the form is valid I should be able to see the button enabled, and in chrome it is working as expected but not in IE 11 (no errors in the console), looked at few solutions but that hasn't fixed my error, any suggestions ??

Comment: whats not working in IE11? Is it that the button is not disabled by default? or that the button doesnt become enabled?

Comment: It doesn't become enabled, even though the form is valid @C_Ogoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` fixed my issue.

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
 this.changeRef.detectChanges();
});
```